# How to find the orientation that uses the least amount of support material in CURA?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, support-structures

I want to print a protein model, given any orientation there are a large number of overhangs, making it difficult to judge by eye which orientation uses the least support material.

Is there a tool in CURA that will try many orientations and pick the one requiring the least amount of support material?